# Symfony 2 : custom twig error page won't work

Tags: symfony, twig

I created a template `app/Resources/TwigBundle/view/Exception/error.html.twig`.
In my `app_dev.php` I've got `$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false);` and in my `app.php` I've got `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);`.
I cleared the cache with `php app/console c:c --env=prod`
I double checked my env by dumping `app.environment` which returns `prod`.
In my `routing.yml` I even put then delete

```
_errors:
resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
prefix:   /_error
```

to test in prod  `www.mydomain.com/_error/404` and there I can see my custom error page.

I set the permission with this command

```
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

The file `app/logs/prod` contains my NotFoundException.
But if I try `www.mydomain.com/azerty` I still got the [green Dev environment](http://symfony.com/doc/current/_images/exceptions-in-dev-environment.png) error page, without the log (not even the [default prod error page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/_images/errors-in-prod-environment.png) )

--
**FIXED**: [Fixed by turning off debugMode](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html#executing-an-application-in-different-environments) `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', **false**);`
Thank you Miro.

Comment: Is there a reason why you would not create these templates in standard directory `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception` ? (as described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html)

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. My templates are in `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/`

Comment: try to create `error404.html.twig` template (you can copy it from your `error.html.twig` file)

Comment: I did, `created error404.html.twig` but still doesn't want to show. Thank you

Comment: by "default sf2 error page" you mean this ? http://symfony.com/doc/current/_images/errors-in-prod-environment.png

Comment: Sorry I should have been way more specific. This is not even the "default" prod page, this is the Dev environment error page, without the logs. I edit my post

Comment: ok, so you either are running the domain in "dev" environment, or you are running "prod" environment in debug mode: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html#executing-an-application-in-different-environments
Can you double check this ? (for example remove/backup/rename whole "dev" environment filebase)

Comment: I did like mentionned in your link and set the second argument to false `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` to disable debug mode and now I can see my customized error page. Thank you very much !